# Printing full symbolic link information, starting from a root directory

Tags: linux, unix

We are interested in printing all the symbolic link information, starting from a root directory.  We would like the information to be printed in the following format:
`symbolic name -> actual name`       *[Notice the same line]*

We have tried the following and it gives us the symbolic name and actual name, **but on different lines**:
`find . -type l -print -exec readlink -f {} \;`

Comment: I think somebody was in a hurry, and decided to vote for closing this question without reading it fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using GNU find:

```
find . -type l -printf '%p -> %l\n'
```

The `%p` format is the file name and `%l` the target of a symbolic link (or blank for other file types)